# How to robustly check Wikipedia pages via API using search terms of different casing

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

I have a website which allows users to submit photos of wildlife. Once uploaded, they can identify the specie on the photo, for example "Polar bear".

This triggers me to get information from Wikipedia about that specie, using that search term:

```
$query =  "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=" . $query;
$pages = file_get_contents($query);
```

Such a query returns one of the following:

- An array of pageids, which I can then query for that page's content
- Nothing, because there simply isn't any match
- a REDIRECT result, which allows me to resolve the page with the proper name

The problem I have has to do with casing. For example, the search term "Milky stork", returns nothing, not even a redirect. "Milky Stork" does work. Uppercasing each word in the query is not a solution either, as it could be that some pages are in lowercase, whereas the uppercase query does not work. There's no consistency.

I'm looking for a way to make this more robust. It shouldn't be that a query fails because of wrong casing, which cannot even be predicted on the user's side.

Does anyone know of a solution for this? Other than trying every possible combination of casings?

**Note:** Some may suggest to use dbpedia instead, but this is no solution for my total needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there is no easy solution - read http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch#Note_on_case_sensitivity

You can try instead use opensearch to find appropriate casing (if normal query returns nothing usable):
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=milky+stork&namespace=0&suggest=
will give you

```
    ["milky stork",["Milky Stork"]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alex. That works. You say it's not an easy solution but it only took me a few line of code to use your suggestion and now it supports all casing variants!

Answer (score 1):

I think trying every possible combination is a viable solution. So, your query might look like:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Milky stork|Milky Stork
```

Note that the first letter is not case-sensitive on Wikipedia.

Comment: I didn't know you could use the "|" character to include multiple search queries. For now I'm sticking to the above answer though, since I have already coded it and it works great so far.